# Python LXML findall then give a path

Tags: python, lxml

How can I get the path for the founded elements?

```
tree = et.parse(inputFile)
root = tree.getroot()
items = root.findall(".//ns:COMPU-METHOD/[ns:CATEGORY='TEXTTABLE']", ns)
   for enums in items:
        enumName = enums.find('ns:SHORT-NAME', ns).text
        path = ?
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a short, representative sample of `inputFile`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "path". You can get a list of elements going back to the root by calling each element's `getparent` in turn. LXML converts attribute and text nodes to dictionaries and strings, so any parent information is lost, but it works for the element

```
def get_element_path(e):
    elems = []
    while e:
        elems.append(e)
        e = e.getparent()
    return "/" + "/".join(e.tag for e in elems)
```

This will tell you the element names, but it is not a full XPATH to the object if any of the elements have more than 1 child element.